Rate Limiter Symfony in ApiPlatform
I want to implement a Rate Limiter for an endpoint that I have defined in a resource with Api Plaform as follows.
App\User\Application\DTO\UserForm:
    operations:
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get:
            status: 404
            read: false
            output: false
        new_user:
            class: ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post
            method: POST
            uriTemplate: /new_user
            messenger: true
            output: false
            status: 202

This resource is a DTO, which implements some Symfony validations, which I need to be executed before consuming tokens from the limiter. After the limiter, this DTO goes to an asynchronous queue, where I do not want the message to arrive, if the limiter has reached the limit.
I have thought about putting a controller, which will have as its only responsibility to consume the tokens. But ApiPlatform, discourag using controllers. So, is there a better place to place this token consumer with Api Platform?

Please read General Design Considerations document that's linked on the page you linked

When updating a state (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE HTTP methods), it’s up
to the developer to properly persist the data provided by API
Platform’s resource object hydrated by the serializer. To do so, there
is another interface to implement: ProcessorInterface.

So if your goal is to have the limiter for persist operation only, you can go with persister which wraps standard doctrine persister and uses rate limiter.
For GET operations, you can implement provider which again calls rate limiter or wraps standard provider.
Alternatively, you can always use Symfony Listener in which you just check if route or path is matching your criteria and conditionally uses rate limiter.
